# Changing the Hibernate File Location in Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, ssd, hibernate

I want to move my hibernate file a non-boot-drive disk.  I see that the pmset utility is the way to do this but the documentation says that the file must reside on the boot drive.  Does anyone know of a way around this restriction?  I just don't want 6GB of my SSD being eaten up on a rarely used file that would probably get written and read faster on a HDD anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you should be able to [move the hibernation file](http://explanatorygap.net/2006/06/08/moving-the-hibernate-image-file-on-a-macbookpro/) by:

```
sudo pmset -a hibernatefile /Volumes/OtherVolume/sleepimage
```

Comment: I will have to try that, I use sleep a lot and got a dual drive (ssd+hdd) conf in my MBP and I don't want to wear on the SSD to much. All other tips I've found tell me to disable hibernate entirely but I like the extra security.

Comment: I too have an SSD that is getting a bit on the full side. Was debating on just creating a symlink, but ended up doing this instead. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Uggh.. NM. According to the `pmset` documentation the `hibernate file` can only be stored on the root volume =(.. [UPDATE] - I tried it anyways and it works, so far. MBP w/SSD & HD, SSD is root, HD is just extra volume. Sleeps fine, and the hibernate file is created/updated on the HD(non-root).

Answer (score 0):

the file you are referring to is /var/vm/sleepimage. that file is only written when the computer is in safe sleep (hibernate, not regular sleep). why not symlink it to the volume you want it to reside.

```
sudo rm /var/vm/sleepimage
sudo ln -s /Volumes/MyHD/sleepimage /var/vm/sleepimage
```

i haven't tested this myself, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: I've thought about that but kind of wanted to see if anyone had sucessfully done it before.  I'm thinking it won't work because if it is coming out of hibernate the system won't have mounted the second drive on that path.  Really I came here to see if any one had some deeper knowledge on the subject because I don't want to end up corrupting my account which is file vaulted.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't move the sleepimage, but you could use [SmartSleep](http://www.jinx.de/SmartSleep.html) to limit you laptop to only hibernate when your battery is below a certain level.

Comment: That doesn't really help any because the space will still be used on the disk which is the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Well, it can also disable hibernation entirely.